# Connecting all elements in list with infix operator

Tags: sml, smlnj

So I have a list lets say **[t, f, f, t, f]** and an infix operator **<==>**. I want to connect the elements so the end result will look like this **t <==> f <==> f <==> t <==> f** . The problem that I am having though is that i get this result **t <==> (f <==> (f <==> (t <==> f)))**. I know why this is happening because the resursion returns all previous elements but I have no idea how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
fun connect(l) =
    case l of
      x::[] => x
      | x::xs => x1 <==> connect(xs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the end result will look like this **t <==> f <==> f <==> t <==> f**.
>
> problem is that i get this result **t <==> (f <==> (f <==> (t <==> f)))**

`x <==> y <==> z` could mean either `(x <==> y) <==> z` or `x <==> (y <==> z)`.

If it is a problem that you fold to one side, try folding to the other:

```
fun connectLeft (x::xs) = foldl (op <==>) x xs
fun connectRight (x::xs) = foldr (op <==>) x xs
```

You can see how [`foldl` and `foldr`](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/mosmllib/List.sml#L84) are implemented.

Or you can see the illustration of [folds as structural transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#As_structural_transformations) (Wikipedia).

---

**Edit:** Assuming **x <==> y <==> z** means **(x <==> y) && (y <==> z)**:

```
fun connect [] = ?
  | connect [x] = ?
  | connect [x,y] = x <==> y
  | connect (x :: y :: rest) =
      (x <==> y) && connect (y :: rest)
```

- `&&` is not the name of SML's built-in logical and-operator, which is called `andalso`. If `x <==> y` returns a `bool`, then perhaps you mean to use `andalso` here.
- Since `connect` supposedly returns either a `bool` or some user-defined truthy value, then maybe `connect [x] = x`, but maybe not.
- In any case, `connect []` should be considered: Is there a good default here, so that the function does not crash on empty lists?

---

If you want to write this using list combinators (like `map`, `foldl`, etc.) instead of manual recursion, what you can do is:

1. Convert the input list into a list of pairs, so `[x, y, z]` becomes `[(x, y), (y, z)]`. There is an SML function called `zip`, hiding away in the library `ListPair`... a few examples that might hint at how to do this:

   ```
   ListPair.zip [x1,x2,x3] [y1,y2,y3] = [(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)]
   ListPair.zip [x1,x2,x3] [x1,x2,x3] = [(x1,x1), (x2,x2), (x3,x3)]
   ListPair.zip [x1,x2,x3] [y2,y3]    = [(x1,y2), (x2,y3)]
   ```
2. Call `map (op <==>)` over the list of pairs.
3. Fold over the result with some `&&` operator.

Comment: This would work as you described but it is unfortunately not the result I am looking for. Because I want this structure x <==> y <==> z. Where all the elements are lets say equal

Comment: If <==> is associative (in the mathematical sense), it should not matter which way your syntax tree is leaning, since any combination would decipher unambiguously using a pre-order traversal. When you say "I want this structure x <==> y <==> z", what do you mean? Surely regardless of what order you combine the elements, eventually, some element must be combined with another, and eventually their combination must be combined with something third, at which point you have implicit parentheses. I cannot say that this question is yet answerable. >_<

Comment: Maybe "x <==> y <==> z" means "x is equal to y, and y is equal to z(, and x is also equal to z)"? In that case I can see how "x <==> (y <==> z)" is not the same, since "t <==> (f <==> f)" would give t and not f. Perhaps you can clarify your question if this or some other interpretation is the right one.

Comment: yes it is exactly as you meantioned in the second example. Basically in the list the equality is betwen two elements and than the other two also. So if we have 3 elements there are 2 equalities and if we have 4 elements there are 3 exualities. Or lets say I gave an example we have the list Equality [x,y,z] . That would mathematically mean (x <=> y) && ( y <=> z). So that is why I dont waht the () in there but just the normal y <==> y <==> z. I hope I was more specfic now :)

Comment: Thanks that is what I am looking for :) only one question after I map my pairs with <==> how do I fold over with the && infix. Since foldr (op &&) x xs will not give the intended result

Comment: @TenebrisNocte: This appears to be a never-ending question. I've deliberately left this as an exercise. Try and connect the the three parts, first by creating pairs of adjacent `x`'es, and then try and do something with those pairs.